# Select recent date, not in an array of PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, date

How to select recent date, not in an array of php?

ie assume I have an array

```
Array ( [0] => 21/07/2013 [1] => 22/07/2013 [2] => 23/07/2013 [3] => 24/07/2013 [4] => 25/07/2013 [5] => 26/07/2013 [6] => 27/07/2013 [7] => 28/07/2013 [8] => 29/07/2013 [9] => 30/07/2013 [10] => 04/08/2013 )
```

and present date is  `20/07/2013`.

I need to check the array, and need to find the recent date which is not in the array. ie In this case, dates `21/07/2013 to 30/07/2013` are in array and `31/07/2013` is the recent date, I need to get.

How could I?

Comment: You can't get a value out of an array which isn't even in it. Tell us what do you want to achieve and why, perhaps there are better solutions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'recent date' ? The date following the last date in the array?

Comment: convert all dates to seconds, sort it and choose first date that is larger, than current date in seconds

Comment: The array basically has a group of random dates, ie `04/07/2013, 06/07/2013` etc... I need to get the very next date, not in that particular array. ie If today is `03/07/2013`, I need to get `05/07/2013` as output even `04/07/2013` is the very next date.  Because `04/07/2013` is in the array, So I need to get past it and need to look for the next date. If it is in the array I need to get past that too and look for next date and so on.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a simple while loop and the DateTime class?

```
function getRecentDate(array $dates, $startDate) {
    // Set up some utilities
    $oneday = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $format = 'd/m/Y';

    // Build a DateTime object from the start date
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $startDate);

    // Add one day and continue if date is in array
    do {
        $date->add($oneday);
        $str = $date->format($format);
    } while (in_array($str, $dates));

    // Return string representation of the date
    return $str;
}

$dates = array('21/07/2013', '22/07/2013', '23/07/2013', '04/08/2013'); 
echo getRecentDate($dates, '20/07/2013');  // output: 24/07/2013
```